# Переворачивание оси координат view элемента

Tags: android

Есть view и если на нем рисовать график, то `Y` начинается с верху, как сделать, чтобы это было, как Декартова система координат?

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setRotationX(180);
```

Answer (score 0):

за 0 взять `Y = view.getHeight()`, потом  `Y` уменьшать

Comment: Это понятно, и тут есть сложность:
Если у нас предположим высота view 200 px а отрисовать нужно линию в 120 px, таким образом получается что если что длинна будет (200 - 120 ) 80, если отнимать, а нужно 120.

Comment: Если только делать вот так: 200 - (200 -120), тогда получается, нужно потестить на железке!!!